# Querying database with eloquent to get a sum of values for statistics charts

Tags: laravel, eloquent, statistics, sum

I have a database table that registers the hits for each class (the `class_id` and I'm trying to query the DB table using Laravel Eloquent to get data, separately as below, to use with charts.

Database table structure:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id          | bigint unsigned  | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| class_id    | bigint unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| hits        | bigint unsigned  | NO   |     | 0                 |                   |
| hit_date    | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| year        | year             | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| quarter     | tinyint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| month       | tinyint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| week        | tinyint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| created_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| deleted_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The data sets that I'm trying to get:

1. Total hits like "SUM(hits) AS total_hits" by year (e.g. 2022, 2023, 2024);
2. Total hits like "SUM(hits) AS total_hits" by quarter (e.g. 2023 quarter 1,2, 3, and 4);
3. Total hits like "SUM(hits) AS total_hits" by month (E.g. last 12 months to display hits/month);
4. Total hits like "SUM(hits) AS total_hits" by day (E.g. total hits for the current month);

The last one (4) I was able to do it with:

```
Statistics::select(DB::raw("SUM(`hits`) as total_hits"))
->where('class_id', 1)
->where('year',now()->year)
->where('month',now()->month)
->get();
```

My problem is getting data, for examples 1, 2, and 3, using Eloquent.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not specified, I assume that there may be multiple hits for each date.

1. Total hits by year

```
$result = Statistics::select('year')
                    ->selectRaw('sum(hits) total_hits')
                    ->where('class_id', 1)
                    ->groupBy('year')
                    ->orderBy('year')
                    ->get();
```

this returns a collection of rows containing the *year* and the *total_hits* value

or more simply in this form if you mean "the total hits for a specific year"

```
$totalHits = Statistics::where('class_id', 1)
                       ->where('year', 2021)
                       ->sum('hits');
```

2. Total hits by quarter

```
$theYear = 2021;

$result = Statistics::select('quarter')
                    ->selectRaw('sum(hits) total_hits')
                    ->where('class_id', 1)
                    ->where('year', $theYear)
                    ->groupBy('quarter')
                    ->orderBy('quarter')
                    ->get();
```

this returns a collection of rows containing the *quarter* and the *total_hits* value for the given year (*$theYear*)

otherwise if you only want the total for a specific year and quarter you can do so:

```
$totalHits = Statistics::where('class_id', 1)
                       ->where('year', 2021)
                       ->where('quarter', 1)
                       ->sum('hits');
```

3. Total hits by month

```
$classId = 1;
$monthsWanted = 12;
 
$lastMonths = Statistics::select('year', 'month')
                        ->distinct()
                        ->where('class_id', $classId)
                        ->orderByDesc('year')
                        ->orderByDesc('month')
                        ->limit($monthsWanted);
          
$statisticsTbName = (new Statistics())->getTable();
 
$result = Statistics::select(["$statisticsTbName.year", "$statisticsTbName.month"])
                    ->selectRaw('sum(hits) total_hits')
           
                    ->joinSub($lastMonths, 'last_months', function ($join) use ($statisticsTbName) {
                            $join->on("$statisticsTbName.year", '=', 'last_months.year')
                                 ->on("$statisticsTbName.month", '=', 'last_months.month');
                      })
                     
                    ->where('class_id', $classId)
                    ->groupBy("$statisticsTbName.year", "$statisticsTbName.month")
                    ->orderBy("$statisticsTbName.year")
                    ->orderBy("$statisticsTbName.month")
                    ->get();
```

this returns a collection of rows containing the *year*, the *month* as a number and the relative *total_hits* value for the last *$monthsWanted* months and for the *$classId* class_id.
Since the *Statistics* model has a non-canonical name I have also introduced the *$statisticsTbName* to be indipendent from the DB table name.

4. Total hits by day

```
$now = now();

$result = Statistics::select('hit_date')
                    ->selectRaw('sum(hits) total_hits')
                    ->where('class_id', 1)
                    ->where('year', $now->year)
                    ->where('month', $now->month)
                    ->groupBy('hit_date')
                    ->get();
```

this returns a collection of rows containing the date and the *total_hits* value for each day for the current month. The $now variable avoids any problems when executing the query at 23:59:59 on the last day of the month.

You can also use:

```
$result = Statistics::selectRaw('extract(day from hit_date) day')
          .......
```

to get the day as a number instead of a date.

Otherwise if you only want the "total hits for the current month" you can do so:

```
$totalHits = Statistics::where('class_id', 1)
                       ->where('year', $now->year)
                       ->where('month', $now->month)
                       ->sum('hits');
```